# How can I make a IQueryable of Generic Type in LINQ C#?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have a method that takes an Id with name `PcId` on basis of that I am trying to retrieve data from different tables , how can I make a generic IQueryable ?

```
                    IQueryable<T> queryAble = null; 
                    switch (pcType)
                    {
                        case "Pc1":
                            queryAble = _context.Pc1Remarks.Where(x => x.Pc1id == pcId).AsQueryable();
                            break;
                        case "Pc2":
                            queryAble = _context.Pc2Remarks.Where(x => x.Pc2Id == pcId).AsQueryable();
                            break;
                        case "Pc3a":
                            queryAble = _context.Pc3aRemarks.Where(x => x.Pc3aId == pcId).AsQueryable();
                            break;
                        case "Pc3b":
                            queryAble = _context.Pc3bRemarks.Where(x => x.Pc3bId == pcId).AsQueryable();
                            break;
                        case "Pc4":
                            queryAble = _context.Pc4Remarks.Where(x => x.Pc4Id == pcId).AsQueryable();
                            break;
                        case "Pc5":
                            queryAble = _context.Pc5Remarks.Where(x => x.Pc5Id == pcId).AsQueryable();
                            break;
                        default:
                            return Tuple.Create("PC Type is not valid", new List<PcRemarksModel>());
                    }
```

Right now its giving error on all cases

[image]

Comment: You have to project to `PcRemarksModel` in each query individually `.Select(x => new PcRemarksModel { ... } )`, then all `queryable` become `IQueryaable<PcRemarksModel>`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv this will not work if the context is a LINQ to SQL connection, or any connection where the evaluation has not happened and it is building up a query which an ORM will transform into the native query language (i.e. SQL). For example, It will fail when trying to map the PcRemarksModel to that native SQL type, since SQL does not have a notion of that type it it's language. Your solution will only reliably work with IEnumerables.

Comment: You can cast it directly just use it like the following line:
`queryAble = ((IQueryable<T>)_context.Pc1Remarks.Where(x => x.Pc1id == pcId).AsQueryable());`

Comment: You'll probably have to cast through `object`, as usual

Comment: Show full method, with signature. I do not understand why it is generic.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that based on provided code this is example of how generics should not be used and how they were not supposed to be used. As for workarounds - you can try casting to `(IQueryable<T>)` (assuming that `T` is corresponding `Pc1Remark`, `Pc2Remarks` ... or how the entities types are called):

```cs
IQueryable<T> queryAble = null; 
switch (pcType)
{
    case "Pc1":
         queryAble = (IQueryable<T>)(_context.Pc1Remarks.Where(x => x.Pc1id == pcId));
         break;
    // ... the same in the other cases
}
```

Though I would repeat - ideally this method should not be generic in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but even this line is giving error ```IQueryable<T> queryAble```

Comment: @Wasim what error does it produce?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found

Comment: @Wasim please add the signature of the method (and possibly declaration of class) were the code is present. It seems that you have some misconception about what generics are.

Comment: Yes you are right :) , I added class now

Comment: @Wasim if any of the answers is working for you - do not forget to mark it as accepted one ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a base class all of the entities you are querying extend, you will want to do

```
IQueryable<Object> queryAble = null;
```

When you want to then evaluate the collection and only get of certain types, you will want to do something like

```
IEnumerable<PC5Remarks> result = queryAble.OfType<PC5Remarks>().Where(...).Select(...).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but it did not work , you wrote ```IEnumerable<PC5Remarks>``` but I am not sure that which type of data would come when query gets executed , it could be ```Pc1Remarks``` , ```Pc2Remarks```, ```Pc3Remarks```  etc